# Process.start System.nullreferenceexception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, process.start

Ok so I am trying to start the process with the following parameters

When I try to start it though I get an System.nullreferenceexception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What am I doing wrong?

```
   Dim exepath As String = Application.StartupPath + "\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
    Dim sr As StreamReader
    Dim cmd As String = " -i """ + input + """ -ar 22050 -y """ + output + """"
    Dim ffmpegOutput As String
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True  'redirect ffmpegs output 
    'to our application
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 'we don’t really need this
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.Start()
```

Comment: The code, as you have shown it, is not capable of throwing a `NullReferenceException`. Something further up in your code is preventing this from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `StreamReader` is not initialized:

```
 Dim sr As StreamReader
```

Verify you are initializing it before using it furthur in the code.

**Edit:**

Since you specify that the exception is thrown on the   `proc.Start()` , I would suggest you to declare a `ProcessStartInfo`, and use it with `Process.Start()`

For example:

```
Dim l As New ProcessStartInfo
l.FileName = exepath
' ...
Process.Start(l)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info: but the error is occurring at proc.start

Comment: @ImranAhmed: please see my answer edit. If that doesn't help, then please add more code to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I managed to get it to work! Essentially, the problem was that I was declaring my process as global and was doing it as dim proc as process not NEW process...